# I need to reset my minecraft viewing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

i pressed f11 which made it take up the full screen so i can't see the "x", minimize or thing in the middle. When i press f11 again it makes it small. What do i do? I have tried restarting my computer but nothing works. It's either too large or it's too small. Help!

Comment: Are you asking how to increase the size of your Minecraft window without making it fullscreen?

Comment: Maximise it with the little square button next to the close button ('x').

Answer (score 2):

F11 toggles between full screen and windowed mode, when the game is in windowed mode you can simply resize the window like any other program.

Answer (score 2):

simply press `F11` again to disable it.
you can click the button that displays a sqare thats right next to the `X`-Button to maximize the window. Minecraft will be displayed stretched to maximum size but still shows the close button at the top

[image]
<sub>You see thoose three Buttons? Press the one in the middle that shows a sqare to maximize the window</sub>